# How to create this cone item in blender?

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty new to blender, but I'm done with boxmodeling. I tried to create an item of a game for my room, but I struggle a lot with it I tried it several times and in different ways but I have no clue how to do the stuff around the cone and the dark blue outside.

[image: Item]

And this is one of my tries
[image]

Maybe I can get some help and tips?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

what I would do for the top point, is go into **edit mode**, and **wire frame view**, then select your **knife tool**, and cut a straight line just below the point, from there you can **add loop cuts** to play around with and round off that point. then from there I would play around with **curves** to get the strips around the outside, once you have what you want, add in a plane, stretch it out, then **subdivide** a couple times, then assign your plane to the curve.

I hope this helps out.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it this way.

Answer (score -1):

To do the stuff dark blue outside the cone I will use Curves.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's really something I didn't work with yet >.< So I gonna try this.